# Making NIntegrate behave like a listable function

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration

I have a function defined by
$$f(t)=\int\limits_0^t g(x) dx$$
$g(x)$ is a complicated function (specifically the Mittag-Leffler function which has recently been implemented in Mathematica 9 as `MittagLefflerE[a,b,t]`) and so I evaluate this integral numerically using `NIntegrate`. I want to perform two tasks with this function---Plot it as a function of the limit $t$, *and* evaluate it's value at a number of different time instances.  I have stored these values of time in a vector of the form `{t1,t2,t3,...,tn}`. Mathematica's documentation suggests that to plot the function I will have to define it as

`f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x],{x,0,t}]`

which works perfectly fine. However, I cannot use this definition of the function $f$ to now evaluate it's value at every element of my list. I assume the issue is because `NIntegrate` is not listable. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: `Attributes[f]={Listable}` might want to look into using `NDSolve` though so you in a sense only have to evaluate the integral once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [**examples here**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html). Define:

```
f[t_] := NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[x]], {x, 0, t}]
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
```

Check:

```
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {0.738643, 0.803863, 0.11889}

But I am not sure why to plot such function you want to make it listable. You could just do something like:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 7}]
```

or to speed up

```
DiscretePlot[f[t], {t, 0, 7, .1}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I wanted to make it listable because not only do I want to plot the function, I also want it's value at about a 100 discrete points in time. I have these time points generated through another piece of code and saved in a list. I required the function to be evaluated at every point in that list.

Answer (score 1):

I see no conflict between `Listable` and the argument test `_?NumericQ`.  For example:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]

f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, t}]

f[{1, 2, 3, other}]
```

> ```
> {0.666667, 1.88562, 3.4641, f[other]}
> ```

Perhaps you want a different result.  I'll suppose that you would rather have `f[{1, 2, 3, other}]` returned unevaluated because one of the elements is not numeric.  You could do that with:

```
f2[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, t}]

f2[{t__?NumericQ}] := f /@ {t}

f2[{1, 2, 3}]

f2[{1, 2, 3, other}]
```

> ```
> {0.666667, 1.88562, 3.4641}
>
> f2[{1, 2, 3, other}]
> ```

This also illustrates a manual "listable" definition, though it only works on a simple list.  Handling nested lists is possible but more complicated.  What is your goal?

Comment: Thanks, setting the attribute as listable and removing the `?NumericQ` argument test works fine. I'm new to Mathematica after having used MATLAB for many years (I now see the great utility in Mathematica!) so I apologize for my beginners questions! What exactly does the argument test do?

Comment: @G.H.Hardly You shouldn't have to remove `?NumericQ` when using `Listable`.  The test, logically, checks to see if the argument is numeric.  Because `Listable` is applied before DownValue rules this will not conflict with passing `f` a list of arguments, which I illustrate in my answer.